# How to incorporate static pages

Tags: jsf, primefaces, static-pages

I have an existing application to modify. The requirement is to add a few static HTML pages (like about us, terms of use etc) to the existing home page, which is a JSF page.

I did research and found out that, to deliver a JSF page, there needs to be :

1. xhtml page
2. a Managed Bean
3. an entry in the faces-config.xml.

My question is - is the managed bean required for even delivering the static pages?

So far, I have done this:

1. Created aboutus.xhtml
2. Snippet from home page with links :

   ```
   <h:link value="#{defaultPageBundle['about.us.link.label']}" outcome="aboutus"/>
   ```
3. Current faces config for home page:

   ```
   <navigation-case>
       <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
       <to-view-id>/home.jsf</to-view-id>
       <redirect/>
   </navigation-case>
   ```

   When I click the link, it goes to aboutus.jsf, but still shows my default home page. Should I add a managedBean to deliver each of these static pages? Or, am I really missing something in the workflow?

Comment: Why exactly do you think you need a managed bean? Do you need some model in the view? The navigation case is completely irrelevant by the way. It works as good without it as long as you use `<h:link>` for page-to-page navigation.

Comment: I do not need model. I just want to serve the static xhtml pages. I added the h:link, but it (say, aboutus.jsf) always shows the home page (default page) and does not serve my aboutus.xhtml.

Comment: If you don't need a model, then you also don't need a backing bean. Simple as that.

Comment: And please stop putting tags in the title.  I removed it for the second time. Users here browse by tags. If everyone put "JSF - " in front of a title here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf then it would look very awkward and nonsensicial.

Comment: Okay sure. My problem is, my xhtml file doesn't get rendered. can you see my edit?

Comment: Problem is not visible in information posted so far. Works just fine for me. Posting an SSCCE demonstrating the problem instead of asking a generic and conceptual question would help better in solving the concrete problem.

Comment: May be the issue is with the fact that I am trying to edit an existing  large application. Will try to come back and post a clear picture. However, the clarification about ManagedBean helps.